# What is this small shrub with small red berries, and lanceolate, alternate entire leaves?

Tags: identification, shrubs

This shrub is:

- found growing wild in a field
- in New Hampshire, USA; USDA Zone 5
- about 1m (3') tall
- alternate, smooth edged, ~6cm (2.5") long leaves
- growing on a hillside in gravelly, acidic (pH ~5), nutrient-poor soil
- fruit is small (<1cm) and red, containing a single seed ~6mm (1/4") long; it's September (beginning autumn here) and the berries are on the bush -- I'm not sure how long they've been there
- the area was completely cleared (i.e. with a bulldozer) about 5 years ago so the plant is not very old

Close-up of fruit:
[image]

Twig detail:
[image]

Overall:
[image]

Closer:
[image]

My hand in the shot for size reference on leaves.
[image]

Seed detail:
[image]

Bud detail:
[image]

Comment: How many seeds per fruit, and what size and type of seed?

Comment: I have ilex cultivars and they don't look like this in regards to leaf colour or the location of the berries.  Another picture of the berries would help

Comment: Ilex looks possible. I'll inspect some fruits more closely tomorrow and try a better camera for a closeup on the buds. Thanks for the title edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I am going to suggest [Elaeagnus umbellata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elaeagnus_umbellata), Autumn Olive.  Alternate, entire, lanceolate,  red fleshy berries, New Hampshire and is also a nitrogen fixer which helps it to grow in tough environments.

Comment: This does look right, Except possibly the berries. When bstpierre 'inspects' the plant for the seed count and size/type, that should clinch it.

Comment: Here's the US National Park Service's link about the plant: http://www.nps.gov/plants/alien/pubs/midatlantic/elum.htm

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, though I'm trying to figure out whether it's really *E. umbellata* or *E. angustifolia*.

Comment: Autumn olive looks like the more likely candidate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's an Elaeagenus multiflora Goumi. It could be a twin of the one I have in my backyard. The only difference is the fruiting time - mine fruits midsummer here in Wisconsin.

The berries are edible, but they are better if you rub them on your slacks a bit before eating to remove the little whitish raised dots on them. As you noticed, they also have a rather large seed, so aren't a berry you'll probably be eating a ton of. Their flavor does grow on you, though.

---

ETA - bstpierre, here's what I've heard about telling the difference between them (and I've only seen the goumi in person, so I'm not certain):

- Goumi have a mature height of 6-8 feet. Autumn olive are larger at 12-18 feet.
- Goumi berries are larger than autumn olives. Fruit can be up to 2.5 cm long (so, 1/2"-1" long), vs 3/8" for autumn olives.
- Goumi berries fruit mid summer, vs fall for Autumn Olives
- Goumi berries are distributed along the stem, while Autumn Olives tend to hang in clusters.

They are so similar though - it really is quite hard to tell the difference! The fruit size and distribution made me think Goumi, but fruiting time looks like Autumn Olive.

Comment: How do you distinguish between *E. umbellata* and *E. multiflora*? I see some minor differences in the descriptions e.g. on Wikipedia, but I'm not sure what differences are definitive.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question here: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/14146/51 Your edit would be welcome there as an answer.

Comment: I'll copy it over, then. I'm really interested to see if someone else has a better answer, though. This is a tough one!