# How to distinguish between Elaeagnus umbellata and E. multiflora?

Tags: identification, shrubs

(This is a follow-up to [this identification question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14108/what-is-this-small-shrub-with-small-red-berries-and-lanceolate-alternate-entir)).

How can one distinguish between *Elaeagnus umbellata* and *E. multiflora*?

I see some minor differences in the descriptions e.g. on Wikipedia, but I'm not sure which differences are definitive.

I was convinced by the first answer that I have an umbellata, but when the second answer arrived I realized that I have no clue how to be sure which is which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually distinguish between them by the drupes. There is some overlap here, but less than there is on leaf size, width, color etc. The fruits (drupes) are usually more consistent. [*Elaeagnus umbellata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elaeagnus_umbellata) has darker, rounder fruit on a shorter stem. [*Elaeagnus multiflora*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elaeagnus_multiflora) has slightly elongated, slightly more orangish fruits hanging from longer stems. Fruit size is variable. See comparison pictures below.

Left: Berries of *Elaeagnus umbellata*. Right: Berries of *Elaeagnus multiflora*.

[image][image]

From [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncFtR.jpg) on your [previous question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14108/what-is-this-small-shrub-with-small-red-berries-and-lanceolate-alternate-entir), I believe the plant you have is *Elaeagnus umbellata*, as suggested in [this accepted answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14108/what-is-this-small-shrub-with-small-red-berries-and-lanceolate-alternate-entir/14114#14114) (vote given).